# How to print a variable's value without a space

Tags: python, variables, space

Simple question but cannot find a simple solution. If I have this code:

```
print("I don't like",FavColour,", I prefer Red")
```

It prints:

```
I don't like FavColour , I prefer Red
```

How do I get rid of the space between `FavColour` and the comma `,` as I want my work to be grammatically correct. If I remove the commas, it becomes a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

Either construct the entire string instead of passing pieces to `print()`:

```
print("I don't like" + FavColour + ", I prefer Red")
```

or use [`print()`'s `sep` argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) to change the spaces to nothing:

```
print("I don't like",FavColour,", I prefer Red", sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
print("I don't like " + FavColour + ", I prefer Red")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine Strings using the '+' sign, this way it will not print out an extra space. But if you are trying to print out a number/decimal you might have to cast it to a string using str(number/decimal) to convert it into a string. If this doesn't work let me know, I'm kind of rusty on Python.

Comment: Thanks, it works great! Edit: It seems like you aren't allowed to just say Thanks so...